# Buying Bulk domain names

Tags: domain

Is there a site that offers a discount on domain names if have something like 25 or more? (currently I only have 5)

Answer (score 1):

godaddy.com give discounts for bulk purchases

Comment: Plus, their % and per-domain coupons usually apply regardless of the # of domains you purchase.  Just search for 'godaddy coupon codes' and you should be able to buy them for ~$6/apiece in bulk.